# Is Flash pushing Wonder Women's sword is some comic book reference or a mythological analogy?

Tags: reference, dc-extended-universe, comic-adaptation, justice-league

In *Justice League*, there is an iconic scene where the Flash helps Wonder Woman get her sword by giving it a push:

[image]
[image]

However, with Zack Snyder as director, this could likely be either a comic book reference or some kind of mythological analogy, or both.

It kind of reminded me of [The Creation of Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Creation_of_Adam)

[image]

Am I right with this analysis? Or am I just over thinking it?

Comment: I'm overthinking/analyzing this now along with you. Thanks Man :D

Answer (score 5):

Well, in the movie The Flash says that he doesn't really 'fight' people that he basically just pushes people and runs away.

This was an example of him pushing something.

I suppose it's also a reference to The Creation of Adam, since Wonder Woman is, quite literally, *a God* and the Flash is a human. His 'nudge' is doing as little as possible, just like Adam's extension of his finger. So you could be on to something - but I think the fact that Barry Allen is a meta-human detracts from that point.

Answer (score -1):

Zack Snyder is known for including as many **Christian** refernces as possible. Case in point, the depiction of Superman as Jesus, the frequent references of Heaven and Hell by Lex Luthor and so on... And so obviously, Zack Snyder paid homage to the creation of Adam with this scene...